# Non-conformant argument with 3-d matrix and vector

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to perform the following element-wise addition between a 3-d matrix and a vector.

```
for l = 1:dim
    M_star(j,k,:) .+= 15*x(j,:).*x(k,:).*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)./(nm.^7) - (l == j)*3*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:).*(sum(x.^2))./(nm.^7) - (l == k)*3*(x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)).*(sum(x.^2))./(nm.^7)
endfor
```

But I got the following error:

```
error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 101x101x101, op2 is 101x101)
```

I have checked that the addition works for a single vector, for example

```
A .+= 15*x(j,:).*x(k,:).*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)./(nm.^7) - (l == j)*3*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:).*(sum(x.^2))./(nm.^7) - (l == k)*3*(x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)).*(sum(x.^2))./(nm.^7)
```

works where A is initialized as

```
A = zeros(1,N) % N = 101 in this case
```

x, x_t, nm are 1 x 101 vector, while j, k, l are variables.

```
% initial conditions
x0 = sin(2.5*pi*SpaceSpan);
x = ones(dim, 1)*x0; % initial states
x_t = x
nm = zeros(1, N);
M_star = zeros(N,N,N);
```

but the following doesn't work either

```
M_star(j,k,:) .+= A
```

Thank you very much.

Edit: Full code

```
% Generalized Newtonian with a simple Crank-Nicolson method (implicit method)

clc;
clear;

% initialize
k = 0.01; % space step
h = 0.01; % time step
T = 10;
dim = 10; % number of dimensions
SpaceSpan = (0:k:1);
TimeSteps = round(T/h);
N = length(SpaceSpan);

% initial conditions
x0 = sin(2.5*pi*SpaceSpan);
x = ones(dim, 1)*x0; % initial states
x_t = x
x_tt = x
b = ones(dim, 1)*x0;
gradb = zeros(dim, dim, N);
nm = zeros(1, N);

MaxSteps = 1000000;  % max steps for path evolution
TolErr = 1e-6;    % termination tolerance

TimeSteps = round(T/h);
XSpan = (0:k:1);

% generate important matrices
L2 = (-2*diag(ones(N-4,1)) + diag(ones(N-5,1),-1) + diag(ones(N-5,1),1))/k^2;
L4 = (6*diag(ones(N-4,1)) - 4*diag(ones(N-5,1),-1) - 4*diag(ones(N-5,1),1) + diag(ones(N-6,1),-2) + diag(ones(N-6,1),2))/k^4;
M_star = zeros(N,N,N) % M star matrix

% reparametrization
c = zeros(N,1);
c(end) = 1/k^2;

% evolution
for i = 1:TimeSteps
  x_ = x % old x
  b_ = b % old b
  gradb_ = gradb % old Jacobian matrix b

  for w = 1:N
    nm(w) = sqrt(sum(x(:,w).^2))
    if (w == 1)||(w == N)
      x_t(:,w) = 0
      x_tt(:,w) = 0
    else
      x_t(:,w) = (x(:,w+1)-x(:,w-1))/2/k
      x_tt(:,w) = (x(:,w+1)-2*x(:,w)+x(:,w-1))/k^2
    end
  end

  %%
  for j = 1:dim % assign value to b
    b(j,:) = -x(j,:)./nm.^3
    for k = 1:dim % assign value to Jacobian matrix gradb
      if j == k
        gradb(j,k,:) = (sum(x.^2).-3*x(j,:).^2)./(nm.^5)
        for l = 1:dim
          M_star(j,k,:) .+= (15*x(j,:).^2.-3*sum(x.^2)).*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)./(nm.^7) - (l == j)*6*sum(x.^2).*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)./(nm.^7) % unable to perform compounded addition
        endfor
      else
        gradb(j,k,:) = -3*x(j,:).*x(k,:)./(nm.^5)
        for l = 1:dim
          M_star(j,k,:) .+= 15*x(j,:).*x(k,:).*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)./(nm.^7) - (l == j)*3*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:).*(sum(x.^2))./(nm.^7) - (l == k)*3*(x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)).*(sum(x.^2))./(nm.^7)
        endfor
      end
    endfor
  endfor

  % implicit method, note that M* is derived explicitly (backward in time)

  x(3:end-2) = inv(L4 - (gradb.' + gradb)*L2)*(x(3:end-2) + M_star*x_t(3:end-2) - gradb.'*b) % implicit solve
  % plot
  if mod(i,PlotFrequency) == 0
    subplot(1,2,1);
    set(data,'xdata',SpaceSpan,'ydata',u)
    title(['Steps=',num2str(i),' Change=',num2str(change)]);

    subplot(1,2,2);
    plot([1:TimeSteps],integrand);
    title(['Integrand of action (action=',0,')']);
    drawnow;
  end   
endfor
```

Comment: Are you using Octave? If yes, please make the correction in the tags

Comment: Yes I am using Octave, is it much different from matlab?

Comment: There are many similarities, and there are differences as well. But tagging it wrong can lead to irrelevant solutions. So please take care of it. Please also provide a small sample of the input matrices that your code uses so that we may run your code to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your problem

Comment: Regarding the edit, if `x`, `x_t` and `nm` are 1x101 vectors then `j`, `k` and `l` must be one, otherwise you're trying to use invalid indices since there is only one row. Hence the purpose of your loop is also lost if `l` equals `1`. Please see [MCVE] and then [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: I edited as requested, is it sufficient or I still need to change?

Comment: @Huy-HoàngNguyễn provide code that we can copy paste and run.  The current code can not be used like that.Also try to explain what equation you are triying to apply. Its quite complex the one you have for us to guess

Comment: Hi, I have added my full code. I'm implementing numerical methods to solve a 4-th order PDE (namely, Euler-Lagrange equation). When I take second-order derivative of b(x) = -x/|x|^3, I will get a 3-tensor and it gets me into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the following:

suppose ABC is 101x101 and suppose M_star is 101x101x101

M_star + repmat(ABC,[1,1,101])

For your example: it is really hard to read, and I don't know what j, k, nm, and x are. In general: Up to 2 dimensions, Matlab is lenient on ill-defined operations, but from 3 onwards, you have to be really precise.

Comment: j,k,l are variables, while nm is a 1 x 101 vector. ABC is actually a 1 x 101 vector defined by the RHS of the cumulative sum. For your suggestion, I still got non-conformant argument error

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to handle 3+ dimensions? I tried using for loop and manually assign values but failed. Thanks

Comment: The elements in brackets are how often ABC will be replicated in each dimension, so in my example once in dim-1, once in dim-2, 101 times in dim-3. Add more entries in that vector for dimension 4 and up. For example, repmat(ABC,[1,1,101,102,103,1]) for 102 and 103 replications in dimensions 4 and 5 and simply adding dimension 6 by doing just-a-single replication there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. So, it turns out that I had some dimensional inconsistencies, that is I should have transpose the RHS because the LHS is a column vector while the RHS is a row vector. However, somehow it still does not work and I had to add a temporary vector to store the value. Here is the solution:

```
for j = 1:dim % assign value to b
    b(j,:) = -x(j,:)./nm.^3
    for k = 1:dim % assign value to Jacobian matrix gradb
      if j == k
        gradb(j,k,:) = (sum(x.^2).-3*x(j,:).^2)./(nm.^5)
        for l = 1:dim
          temp .+= ((15*x(j,:).^2.-3*nm.^2).*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)./(nm.^7) - (l == j)*6.*nm.^2.*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)./(nm.^7)).' 
        endfor
        M_star(j,k,:) = temp
      else
        gradb(j,k,:) = -3*x(j,:).*x(k,:)./(nm.^5)
        for l = 1:dim
          temp .+= (15*x(j,:).*x(k,:).*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)./(nm.^7) - (l == j)*3*x(l,:).*x_t(l,:).*(sum(x.^2))./(nm.^7) - (l == k)*3*(x(l,:).*x_t(l,:)).*(sum(x.^2))./(nm.^7)).'
        endfor
        M_star(j,k,:) = temp
      end
    endfor
  endfor
```